# App menu created from keywords

Tags: gui-design, menu, controls, touch-screen, tree

I have application which allow users to select video and play it. I have for each video few keywords and with help of [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) I created tree from these keywords. So now user can go from generally sense to more specified. I want to use this for filtering video. I was trying to search for some great way how to design control like this but I didn't find anything. I have tree and when you click on general term it adds sublevel terms to clicked one. It's good but I want to create something amazing. It's for touch devices and in upper half I have previews of videos. On the right bottom half I have classic folder tree (filtering by folders where are videos saved) and this control I want on the bottom left half.

For better understanding I am posting here actual solution (it's not looks good, it was just testing for creating tree, if tree is okay).

[image: tree from keywords]

Edit: I forget to mention that touch display isn't mobile device but big screen (big monitor). For better understanding I include screen my actual solution.

[image: actual desing of my player]

Comment: I think you could find some reference on the answers to the question [tree-view for mobile devices](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5709/tree-view-for-mobile-devices)

Comment: Is this the same [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) you are referring to in your question?

Comment: @Charles yes it's the same WordNet.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to show someone parts of the path they haven't taken. If you show anything about the path at all, just treat it like a breadcrumb, and show the options that they have chosen.  That also makes it a lot easier to lay it out, as you have a single box / image for each choice.

Here is a rough mockup for what I am suggesting:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it looks good. Better than my solution. I edited my post so It's clear now that it's for bigger screen. But still your solution could be useful for me. Just if you get any better solution just say it :)